# <verb stem>+たかない

Tags: verbs, negation, i-adjectives

Is [verb stem] + たかない different than [verb stem] + たくない? What does it mean?

[image: 11人いる]

Comment: I believe it was discussed somewhere that it's better not to post manga pages if it can be avoided, due to copyright issues. If you could find a way to include the relevant context in the text of your question it would be an upvote from me ;)

Comment: @ジョン Well ianal, but just an image like this.. it should be allowed: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use

Comment: @Pacerier Good point and in this case probably true, but the nature of this community means that allowing something once sets a precedent of acceptance. Would it still be fair use if there was another question with a different page from the same manga? How about 5 more? I'm also NAL so my concerns could be unfounded. Sorry if that's the case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a colloquial, contracted form for ~~たく"は"ない, '(you) wouldn't want to~~'. Just as you say あまくみてはいかん to mean あまくみてはいけない.

Comment: Nitpicking: いかん is not really a contracted form for いけない, but a contracted form for いかぬ, the classical-Japanese equivalent for いけない.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: On the other hand, when one sees forms like 〜んかった, one begins to wonder... (The historically correct form, apparently, is 〜なんだ.)

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto-san, またやってしまいました・・・　ZhenLin-san, What is '~~んかった'??

Comment: @Zhen Lin: That is a good point.  I think that both ～んかった and ～なんだ use different conjugations of negative ぬ from the usual ones in the classical Japanese, but I am not sure.  Chocolate: I suppose that Zhen Lin is talking about the form such as せんかった for しなかった and いかんかった for いけなかった, which I think is used in some dialects (but I cannot point out which dialects).

Comment: @Jesse: I do not know what your comment is supposed to mean.  (Not that I would like to argue about it.)

Comment: @Jesse: I do not know why it _should_ be, but if you prefer that way, I honestly do not care….

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: Sorry if I offended you, I just was trying to point out the semantic difference between `contracted` and `corrupted`, the meaning is different. For example, `I'm` is the contracted form of `I am` in English, whereas `Yah` would be the corrupted form of `Yes`. I hope you understand the difference.

Comment: @Chocolate: I'm curious – you're a native speaker of a western Japanese dialect, yes? How would you express the past tense of a negative verb?

Comment: @ZhenLi-san I just didn't think you were talking about dialectal expressions. And yes, I say 行かへんかった(I didn't go)/見いひんかった(I didn't see)/しいひんかったorせえへんかった(I didn't do) etc.