「早かない」という言葉について
時代劇で「早かない」という言葉が出てきて、初めて聞いたなと思い、検索してみたら、ネット上では色んな人が「早くない」と同じ意味で使ってて実例が多いようです。例を挙げるとこちらへ：1、2、3
しかし、意外にも、よく日本語に関する問題に回答してくれる投稿の多い知恵袋などのサイトではこのような言葉の闡明や討論が見つかりませんでした。文例として、論文『江戸語・明治期東京語における接続助詞ケレド類の特徴と変化』では「早かないわ、もう一晩泊ったんだから。だけどこんな頭をして帰ると何だか可笑しいわね。御嫁にでも行く様で （［明］彼岸過迄）」と説明せずにあります。
文法的には連用詞及び名詞の「早く」が動詞のように活用されたものの様ですが、根拠や資料が見つからなかったので、果たして理論上には正しいのでしょうか？一体何故「早かない」になってるのでしょうか？

It may be a contraction of the particle は, as discussed here: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5222/verb-stemたかない

@Axe Makes perfect sense!

「早かない」は俗語（スラング）だと思います。友達や家族とのくだけた会話の時に使われます。「早くない」に限らず「〜くない」という表現を「〜かない」に変えことがあります。意味は同じですが、相手が冗談交じりに言っており、自分も冗談交じり回答しているというニュアンスや、相手の発言にあきれたようなニュアンスが出ます。漫才で言う、ボケとツッコミのうち、ツッコミと同じニュアンスです。
例えば、友達が大食いで、あなたの分の料理を指さして「これも食べていい？」と聞いてきたとします。このとき、あなたは次のように言ったとしましょう。

よくねーよ。　（ただの否定）
よかねーよ。　（少し冗談交じりの否定）

どちらも意味は同じですが、「よかねーよ」の方が相手がちょっとふざけていて、自分もそれに乗っかって答えていますというニュアンスや、相手が大食いすぎてちょっとあきれたようなニュアンスが出ます。「よかない」はくだけた表現なので、語尾も「ねーよ」のようにくだけた表現のことが多いです。
質問文で挙げてくれた例も（相手は真面目に書いているかもしれませんが）「早かない」を使うことにより、「冗談でしょう？」「ウソでしょう？」というニュアンスが出ています。
「〜かない」は話し言葉で、書くことはあまり無いのですが、XなどのSNSでは、会話の延長線上としてとらえて、くだけた話し言葉のように書く人もいます。
知恵袋は日本語の母語話者が利用している割合が高く、母語話者は普段から友達や家族との会話で「〜かない」を使ったり、聞いたりしているので自然と理解しているからではないかと思います。
